# SQL Parameters not being replaced

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following method and the sql parameter is not being replaced please can someone help me spot what I have done wrong or help me to debug.  Many Thanks in advance.

```html
   function readLike($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page, $searchval){

        $query = "SELECT
        id, company_name, company_reg_number, vat_number
        FROM
         $this->table_name WHERE company_name LIKE ?
        ORDER BY
        company_name ASC
        LIMIT
        {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";

        $searchval = "%".$searchval."%";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $searchval, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
```

I have edited the above post (now working code) It turns out that it was just a case of my an error in the sql command and me not understanding that I couldn't echo the query including the parameters.  Thanks for everyone's help.  I had a single quote next to the percentage symbol on by searchval variable.

Comment: `echo $myquery = "SELECT
        id, company_name, company_reg_number, vat_number, website
        FROM $this->table_name where company_name like ? ORDER BY company_name ASC";` and what do you see?

Comment: I see the question mark

Comment: I see the query string but with the question mark not the parameter.

Comment: bindParam does not substitute ? for the parameter value in the sql statement (the $myquery string) itself. You will always see the ? in $myquery.   When executed, are you not seeing the results that you expect?

Comment: @ross: that's to be expected. your searchval doesn't get "merged" with the query string until **AFTER** the query gets sent to the DB and executed. you'll never see `like '%kittens%'` in anything in PHP.

Comment: understood thanks, im not getting the result I'm expecting.  What is the best way to debug this problem please what ever value I pass in (even an exact match) I get no rows returned.

Comment: @Ross - debug all the things! Firstly, remove the WHERE completely from your function; do you get results? Then try hard-wiring something instead of your variable; do you still get results?

Comment: @MarcB Shouldn't the `$this->table_name` be replaced before then though?

Comment: @andrewsi  good call I'm getting no results without the where clause I think because I misunderstood the situation described by Marc B I was looking at for a problem with parameter replacement but the problem is obviously elsewhere   Thanks for your help, Ill report back when I have found it

Comment: @Uueerdo: yes, but that's because that's php string interpolate. the vars will get replaced with values BEFORE the resulting string gets send to the DB layer. but `?` means nothing to php. that's handled in the DB server.

Comment: @MarcB I see, I wasn't sure whether that should happen before it is assigned to $query, or when $query is passed to `prepare`; I figured perhaps something was interfering with that mechanism, since the "echo" subdiscussion seemed to suggest it was not being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

it looks like you should be doing

`$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchval)`